# How to draw a vertical line at a specified date in a Gantt chart?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath, pgfgantt

I want to add a command to `pgfgantt` package that draw vertical line at a specified date (like the one for the today line). Here's what' I want to get (green line) :

[image]

So I looked to `pgfgantt.sty` to see how the today line was drawn and I came with this code that I added into `pgfgantt.sty` file :

```
\newcommand\drawverticalline[1]{%
 \begingroup%
  \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}%
   \begin{scope}
    \gtt@tsstojulian{#2}{\gtt@today@slot}
    \gtt@juliantotimeslot{\gtt@today@slot}{\gtt@today@slot}%
     \pgfmathsetmacro\x@mid{%
       (\gtt@today@slot - 1 + \ganttvalueof{today offset})%
                  * \ganttvalueof{x unit}%
     }%
     \draw [/pgfgantt/today rule]
                (\x@mid pt, \y@upper pt) -- (\x@mid pt, \y@lower pt)
                node [/pgfgantt/today label node] {\ganttvalueof{today label}};%
     \end{scope}
    \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}%
    \endgroup%
}
```

Now normally I could use the command like this : `\drawverticalline{2014-05-07}` but when I do this I got this error :

```
! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `pt' (in 'pt').
```

The error came from this code :

```
\pgfmathsetmacro\x@mid{%
       (\gtt@today@slot - 1 + \ganttvalueof{today offset})%
                  * \ganttvalueof{x unit}%
     }%
```

that doesn't have `pt` on it. So I decided to comment it and replace `\x@mid` by a constant (5) but now I get this error :

```
! Undefined control sequence.
```

Why I get this error? the command is defined!

Here's the code from `pgfgantt` that draw the today line :

```
\def\@tempa{none}%
\edef\@tempb{\ganttvalueof{today}}%
\ifx\@tempa\@tempb\else%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\x@mid{%
    (\gtt@today@slot - 1 + \ganttvalueof{today offset})%
    * \ganttvalueof{x unit}%
  }%
  \draw [/pgfgantt/today rule]
    (\x@mid pt, \y@upper pt) -- (\x@mid pt, \y@lower pt)
    node [/pgfgantt/today label node] {\ganttvalueof{today label}};%
\fi%
```

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}  
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} % optional
   \begin{ganttchart}[x unit=1.8mm, 
                  y unit chart=0.87cm, 
                  time slot format=isodate, 
                  vgrid=*{5}{dotted},
                 ]
                  {2014-04-14}{2014-07-11}
       \gantttitlecalendar{month=name} \\ 

       \ganttbar[progress=100]{title1}{2014-04-14}{2014-04-15} \\

       \ganttbar[progress=100]{title2}{2014-04-15}{2014-04-17} \\

       \drawverticalline{2014-05-07}
   \end{ganttchart}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: is `@` a letter at the point you make these definitions? Please always provide a complete document that reproduces the problem, not just code fragments.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry I added a MWE. The macros are defined in `pgfgantt` package.

Comment: where is drawverticalline defined?  Your MWE just gives an error that it is not defined

Comment: I added it in pgfgantt package because I need macros defined in the package but are not accessible from outside (y@lower for example)

Comment: Don't ever edit the packages in place!!!! That just makes your distribution incompatible with everything else (and is often against the licence conditions of the file) also you need `#1` not `#2` in your definition. There is never any need to edit the file, you could make that definition in the document the fact that \y@upper is undefined is an error in the way the command is used not where it is defined.

Comment: Do you have a solution to my problem? I don't see any other way to solve it. How I could use `\y@upper` outside the `pgfgantt.sty` file? I have tested it with `#1` and it doesn't work.

Comment: No it doesn't work (and I don't know the package well enough to have a solution) but it works (or not) in exactly the same way whether you put definition in your preamble (between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` or if you put it in the pgfgantt.sty. But you are using pgfgantt.sty under the LPPL licence which says you should rename the file if you edit it, apart from licence reasons renaming files in your standard input tree will confuse your package manager if you are using texlive or miktex or similar. You _never_ need to do that.

Comment: Could you confirm that I can use `\y@lower` that was defined like this : `\pgfmathsetmacro\y@lower{%
    (\gtt@currentline - \ganttvalueof{title top shift}%
    - \ganttvalueof{title height}) * \ganttvalueof{y unit title}%
  }%` in `pgfgantt.sty` from my document? if yes how? For the licence things, I'm just testing it's for my private use.

Comment: Even for private use it's a really bad idea to edit the file.  It only makes a difference where a command is used not where it is defined. If that line works if you put it in pgfgantt.sty it would work if you put it anywhere else such as your document or in a local mygantt.sty loaded after pgrfgantt

Comment: I'm not sure that I can access the macro defined in pgfgant.sty in my document. I tested with this and it doesn't work : `\draw [/pgfgantt/today rule]
                    (5, \y@upper) -- (5, \y@lower)
                    node [/pgfgantt/today label node] {\ganttvalueof{today label}};`

Comment: TeX name scoping does not work the way you seem to think it works, but there is no point me replying to your comments the same way each time saying the location of the definition is not the issue, so I'll stop.

Comment: @user230137 I'm not certain from the above, but it looks to me like you've tried to copy the code in `pgfgantt.sty` for `\draw [/pgfgantt/today rule]`. It's inside a `scope` block, which acts as a TeX group as well as doing some graphics-related stuff. Thus unless you alter the rather complex `ganttchart` main environment you can't use `y@upper`, _etc._ I tried a bit of hacking around with their definitions, but I don't think this is a productive route!

Comment: @JosephWright The first time I have tried to add a command to `pgfgantt.sty`. Like that I could access y@upper and the other macros. But like I said in my question I got errors doing this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Updated Answer

In response to tdgunes' comments about this answer years later, I contacted the package author about this question, and I'm happy to say that he has added this feature to the package as of v5.0, released to CTAN on 11 January 2018!

The code in this section shows how to use the feature as implemented in the package. I've also left the original answer below, because I feel it has value in explaining the best practices for modifying a distributed package when it's necessary.

The package author has added a `\ganttvrule` macro, to be used like this:

```
\ganttvrule[<options>]{<label-text>}{<time-slot-spec>}
```

The optional argument can contain styling options. The available options are described in-depth in the [package manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfgantt/pgfgantt.pdf).

This macro must still be used *after* all rows of the Gantt chart have been defined.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{ganttchart}[
  time slot format=isodate, 
  vgrid=*{5}{dotted},
  today={2014-04-14},
]{2014-04-14}{2014-05-11}
  \gantttitlecalendar{month=name} \\ 
  \ganttbar[progress=100]{title1}{2014-04-14}{2014-04-15} \\
  %\ganttvrule{Fail!}{2014-04-24} % must be placed at the end of the ganttchart environment
  \ganttbar[progress=100]{title2}{2014-04-15}{2014-04-17} \\
  \ganttbar[progress=50]{testing}{2014-04-17}{2014-04-18}
  \ganttvrule{Test 1}{2014-05-07}
  \ganttvrule{Test 2}{2014-04-30}
  \ganttvrule{Test 3}{2014-05-10}
  \ganttvrule{Success}{2014-04-24} % works at the very end
  \ganttset{vrule/.append style={blue}} % change the style
  \ganttvrule{Blue!}{2014-04-28} % check for changed style
    \ganttvrule[vrule/.append style={red, ultra thick}]{Red!}{2014-05-03} % alternate styling method
\end{ganttchart}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

## Original Answer (superseded by `pgfgantt` v5.0, released 2018-01-11)

As noted several times in the comments, directly modifying any file controlled by some package management system (be it `tlmgr`, MikTeX Package Manager, or package managers on any other system, for that matter [RPM, `pacman`, `npm`, etc.]) is a *Very Bad Idea*.™ Licensing issues aside, and even when/if the package manager doesn't get confused, any modifications *will* be lost with an update and your documents using those modifications *will* be broken.

The proper way to do it is to extend the package with your own local customizations. I've illustrated one way to do this here:

1. Create your own package `pgfgantt-custom` (`pgfgantt-custom.sty`) that loads the TeX distribution's current `pgfgantt` package and adds/modifies commands from there.
2. Place this file in a `texmf-local` location* such that LaTeX will find it.

* Refer to [Where do I place my own `.sty` files to make them available to all my `.tex` files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-tex-files) for full details of this procedure for each of the major TeX distributions.

So, create `pgfgantt-custom.sty` with this content:

```
\ProvidesPackage{pgfgantt-custom}[2015/01/10 My local customizations to the pgfgantt package] % name, date, and description of the package
\RequirePackage{pgfgantt} % load the package we're modifying

% some new keys for the style of our "anyday" marker lines
\@gtt@keydef{anyday}{none}
\@gtt@keydef{anyday offset}{1}
\@gtt@stylekeydef{anyday rule}{dashed, line width=1pt}
\@gtt@keydef{anyday label font}{\normalfont}
\@gtt@stylekeydef{anyday label node}{%
  anchor=north, font=\ganttvalueof{anyday label font}%
}

\newcount\gtt@anyday@slot

\newcommand\drawverticalline[2]{%
  \gtt@tsstojulian{#1}{\gtt@anyday@slot}%
  \gtt@juliantotimeslot{\gtt@anyday@slot}{\gtt@anyday@slot}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\y@upper{%
    \gtt@lasttitleline * \ganttvalueof{y unit title}%
  }%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\y@lower{%
    \gtt@lasttitleline * \ganttvalueof{y unit title}%
      + (\gtt@currentline - \gtt@lasttitleline - 1)%
      * \ganttvalueof{y unit chart}%
  }%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\x@mid{%
    (\gtt@anyday@slot - 1 + \ganttvalueof{anyday offset})%
      * \ganttvalueof{x unit}%
  }%
  \draw [/pgfgantt/anyday rule]
    (\x@mid pt, \y@upper pt) -- (\x@mid pt, \y@lower pt)
    node [/pgfgantt/anyday label node] {#2};%
}
```

Here's a breakdown of the code:

---

`\@gtt@keydef`/`\@gtt@stylekeydef` commands:

I created some keys similar to the styling options for the today markers, so these can be changed independently of the today marker style if desired. The defaults are the same as the today marker style.

---

```
\newcount\gtt@anyday@slot
```

This defines the counter where the marked date is manipulated according to `pgfgantt`'s internal macros for processing different date formats.

---

Now, the main event: `\drawverticalline` takes 2 arguments; the first is the date to mark and the second is the marker text (potentially empty).

The first two lines of the definition simply process the date in the same way that is done for `today`. Now comes the part where you ran into troubles. You had no access to `\y@upper`, `\y@lower`, and `\x@mid` because these were defined inside a separate scope. So we have to redefine them inside the scope of this new command.

A side effect of this is that we have no knowledge of if there are any more rows to draw in the Gantt chart (the `today` marker is drawn last internally by `pgfgantt`) and there is no way to defer our command to the end of the `ganttchart` environment. So usage of our new `\drawverticalline` macro must be at the end of the `ganttchart` environment, after all `\ganttbar`s have been drawn.

The rest is drawing the marker, with the appropriate style keys substituted, and the node text is `#2` for the second argument.

### Usage Example

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt-custom}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{ganttchart}[
  time slot format=isodate, 
  vgrid=*{5}{dotted},
  today={2014-04-14},
]{2014-04-14}{2014-05-11}
  \gantttitlecalendar{month=name} \\ 
  \ganttbar[progress=100]{title1}{2014-04-14}{2014-04-15} \\
  %\drawverticalline{2014-04-24}{Fail} must be placed at the end of the ganttchart environment
  \ganttbar[progress=100]{title2}{2014-04-15}{2014-04-17} \\
  \ganttbar[progress=50]{testing}{2014-04-17}{2014-04-18}
  \drawverticalline{2014-05-07}{Test 1}
  \drawverticalline{2014-04-30}{Test 2}
  \drawverticalline{2014-05-10}{Test 3}
  \drawverticalline{2014-04-24}{Success} % works at the very end
  \ganttset{anyday rule/.append style={blue}} % change the style
  \drawverticalline{2014-04-28}{Blue!} % check for changed style
\end{ganttchart}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output:

[image]

You can uncomment the `\drawverticalline{2014-04-24}{Fail}` line to see what happens when we don't yet know the total number of rows in the Gantt chart.

Comment: @Stormie yes, but I recommend doing it this way. :-)

Comment: Were there any attempts to include this into pgfgantt?

Comment: @tdgunes not that I am aware of. But I will send the package maintainer an email pointing to this code—maybe we can get it included! Thanks for asking about it.

Comment: you are welcome. I am not an latex expert yet, but I'd be happy to contribute.

Comment: @tdgunes great news! The package maintainer is going to add this to `pgfgantt`! Many thanks for the suggestion. I'll come back and update this answer when the new version is released.