# Use Font Awesome 3.2.0 on Debian Wheezy

Tags: fonts, moderncv

I'd like to use the Stack Overflow icon in [moderncv](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) via [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/).

Because the icon was added to Font Awesome in [3.2.0](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/251) and the TeX Live distribution on my Debian Wheezy ships with an older version I can't use it.

Is there a way to update Font Awesome manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a much more easier way.

1. Download the font from the [official site](http://fontawesome.io/), *not* the github repo (for some reason it didn't work for me)
2. Install it in your font folder. In linux, usually under `.font`
3. Use fontspec (xetex/lualatex)
4. Add the following code:

   ```
   \newfontfamily{\fontawesome}{FontAwesome}
   ```
5. To use the new stackoverflow icon, add:

   ```
   {\fontawesome }
   ```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{green}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\fontawesome}{FontAwesome}
\title{CV}
\firstname{Matthias}\lastname{Braun}    
\extrainfo{\httplink[{\fontawesome } Stack Overflow: Matthias Braun]{stackoverflow.com/users/775954/matthias-braun}}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{Job experience}
\cventry{March 2013}{Trip to the moon and back}{}{}{}{}{}

\end{document}
```

[image: CV with Awesome Font]

Comment: That's beautiful, thanks! I put the downloaded font awesome folder in `~/.fonts` (plural).

Answer (score 4):

1. Download the latest `FontAwesome.otf` from [the repo](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/tree/master/fonts) and put it
   in `~/texmf/tex/latex/fontawesome-custom`.
2. Create `~/texmf/tex/latex/fontawesome-custom/fontawesome.sty` with this content:

   ```
   \ProvidesPackage{fontawesome-custom}[2015/01/12 My local customizations to the fontawesome package] 
   \RequirePackage{fontawesome} % load the package we're modifying

   \expandafter\def\csname faicon@stackexchange\endcsname      {\symbol{"F16C}}  \def\faStackOverflow     {{\FA\csname faicon@stackexchange\endcsname}}
   ```

If you want to add a different new icon, have a look [here](https://github.com/troyane/FontAwesomeLatex/blob/master/fontawesome-backward.sty) and [here](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/).

You can use the icon like this in your tex file:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\usepackage{fontawesome-custom}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{green}

\title{CV}

% Contact data
\firstname{Matthias}\lastname{Braun}    
\extrainfo{\httplink[\faStackOverflow~Stack Overflow: Matthias Braun]{stackoverflow.com/users/775954/matthias-braun}}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Job experience}
\cventry{March 2013}{Trip to the moon}{}{}{}{}{}

\end{document}
```

Compiling with `lualatex` or `xelatex` produces this:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Quick self-answer? ;-)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again Matthias... `:-)` Modifying a file managed by a Package Manager is not the best idea. A better way would be to make your own local package containing the customizations. You can see an example of how to do that [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/222557/21344).

Comment: Or you can install the modified and renamed copy of the `.sty` into `TEXMFHOME`, and put the updated font either there or in `~/.fonts`. Note that the package is LPPL which means you definitely should rename it if modifying it, in any case.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I adapted the answer accordingly.